# Unsuccessful connection to the server makes it unusable

Tags: c#, tcp

I am facing a problem when multiple clients try to connect to the server with same credentials. Actually, when a client with a same credentials is already connected, a message to the client trying to connect with those credentials is going to be shown, but afterwards no more clients are able to connect. I am not getting any exceptions, nothing breaks, but once I check for client application status in task manager, there stands 'Not responding'.

Client function for connecting to the server:

```
    public TransferClass connectMe(TransferClass transfer)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(transfer.ipAdr))
            {
                ipAdress = transfer.ipAdr.Trim();
            }
            client = new TcpClient(ipAdress, 10000);
            stream = client.GetStream();
            formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            formatter.Serialize(stream, transfer);
            transfer = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as TransferClass;
            return transfer;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            transfer.LoggedIn = false;
            return transfer;
        }
    }
```

Server listening for clients:

```
    void listen()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                socket.Listen(50);
                Socket client = socket.Accept();
                NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(client);
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                TransferClass transfer = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as TransferClass;
                transfer.LoggedIn = true;
                if (connectedList.ContainsKey(transfer.ClientID))
                {
                    transfer.LoggedIn = false;
                    formater.Serialize(stream, transfer);
                    return;
                }
         //code which is executed if everything is OK    
            }
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
            throw;
         }
     }
```

I can successfully debug client and server side, but once a client tries to connect with same `ClientID` first it is checked on the server, and the message that he is not `LoggedIn` is going to be sent back to the client. But after I change the `ClientID` and try to connect again, and follow it with debug, it never enters server side, like `formatter.Serialize` is not working on the client.

`ClientID` is something client enters himself.

My guess is that in the part on the server where I am checking if client with same `ClientID` already exists I should also close the stream, or something like that, but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: `if (connectedList.ContainsKey(transfer.ClientID)) return;` So, server stops listening completely?

Comment: Great, that's the problem. Thanks! What should I use instead of `return` to prevent for other part of code to execute? Should I put everything in `else` part?

Comment: Well, I guess you need to close the client socket and all resources associated with it, and continue listening. For example, `continue` instead of `return`.